# Using string split in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, split

```
    str = "ex1:ex2:ex3"
```

I want to split the string with : delimiter and get only ex1 and ex2, and ignore ex3. When I do,

```
    first, rest = str.split(":")
```

It gives me the following

```
    ex1
   :ex2
```

I tried replacing : with a space

```
    str.gsub(":"," ")
```

But it still gives the same answer with the delimiter (:) with the second part

Is there any good way to split the string using Ruby where I am interested in only the first 2 parts of the string.

Expected answer is:

```
    ex1
    ex2
```

Thanks!!

Comment: `str.split(":")` gives me three exact strings.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? `first, rest = "ex1:ex2:ex3".split(":"); puts first, rest` prints "ext1" and "ext2" for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str = "ex1:ex2:ex3"
first, rest = str.split(/\:/)
print "#{first} and #{rest}"    # output => "ex1 and ex2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this:

```
str = "ex1:ex2:ex3:ex4"

f,s = str.split(':')
f #=> "ex1" 
s #=> "ex2"
```

If you want to return an array:

```
str.split(':').first(2)
  #=> ["ex1", "ex2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way with a regex, too. First, we get only the first 2 groups between `:`, and then remove the rest of the string. And then split:

```
str = "ex1:ex2:ex3".gsub(/^(\w+\:\w+).*$/, "\1")
first, rest = str.split(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

Through sub and gsub. Remove the last colon part and then replace the colons with newline character.

```
> str = "ex1:ex2:ex3"
> str.sub(/:[^:]*$/, "").gsub(/:/, "\n")
=> "ex1\nex2"
```